# Bash проверка на sudo -

Tags: bash, if

Есть кусок скрипта:

```
ssh_user=xxx
ssh_host=10.65.192.14

if [ "$USER" != "root" ]; then
    echo "Для выполнения скрипта нужны права sudo, запустите скрипт с правами суперпользователя"
fi

remuser=$(ssh -t "$ssh_user"@"$ssh_host" "sudo whoami")
echo "debug: $remuser"

if [ "$remuser" != "root" ]; then
    echo "[FAIL] Нет sudo на удаленном сервере $ssh_host"
    exit 1
fi
echo "[-OK-] Права sudo есть на сервере $ssh_host"
```

Запускаю его под обычным пользователем, у xxx на хосте есть права sudo. Если запущу скрипт от sudo - проверка первым if проходим корректно.
Вывод скрипта при запуске от обычного пользователя такой:

```
Для выполнения скрипта нужны права sudo, запустите скрипт с правами суперпользователя
Connection to 10.65.192.14 closed.
debug: root
[FAIL] Нет sudo на удаленном сервере 10.65.192.14
```

Вопрос: Почему первый if работает нормально, а второй if - root за root не считает?

Comment: `$remuser` содержит весь вывод команды. Для предания тестовому коду минимальной осмысленности стоило выполнять на хосте команду `whoami` ну или сохранять содержимое переменной `$USER` с удаленного сервера

Comment: Это только предположение но `-t` вероятнее всего возвращает escape символ `\r` или `\b`, можно проверить `echo "debug: '$remuser'"` потеряется 1 кавычка, поэтому вместо использования псевдотерминала, я бы порекомендовал его отключение `-T`

Comment: ipatev_nn, спасибо, помогло! 
Проверил на кавычки, действительно съедается последняя. Убрал вообще ключ -t из ssh - и заработало как надо. Надо будет почитать, в чем отличие ssh  от ssh -T.

Comment: плохая идея проверять на `sudo`, во первых вместо `sudo` могут использовать тот же `doas`, во вторых есть вариант подключатся как `root` и уже напрямую от него выполнять действия.
по сути достаточно просто заканчивать программу с выводом сообщения что нужны права суперпользователя как это обычно и делается во множестве unix утилит.

Comment: Это внутренний скрипт, на серверах будет только sudo. Итоговый скрипт выполняется на локальной машине, и должен выполнить несколько команд на удаленной из-под рута, но ssh доступен по rsa-ключам под пользователем. Соответственно надо подключиться под пользователем и от sudo выполнить код, который сгенерировали по итогу на локальной машине.

Comment: Необходимости запускать этот скрипт на хосте из-под `sudo` не видно.

Answer (score 0):

Как и сказал **ipatev_nn**, проблема была в ключе -t.

Команда в таком виде приехала "по наследству" из другого места скрипта, где выполнялось ssh -t user@host "sudo bash -c 'переменная с командами в многострок', которая была найдена в каком-то мануале, продебажена и работала в таком виде.
В итоге, переписал переменную в 1 строку в виде: команда1 && команда2 && итд и уже скормил ssh user@host "sudo bash -c 'переменная в однострок'".

Спасибо за подсказку.